# Combining Two Rows with Different Levels according to Some Conditions into One in R

Tags: r

This is a part of my data: (The actual data contains about 10,000 observations with about 500 levels of `SalesItem`)

```
s1<-c('1008','1009','1012','1013','1016','1017','1018','1019','1054','1055')
s2<-c(155,153,154,150,176,165,159,143,179,150)
S<-data.frame(SalesItem=factor(s1), Sales=s2)

> str(S)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ SalesItem: Factor w/ 10 levels "1008","1009",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Sales    : num  155 153 154 150 176 165 159 143 179 150`
```

What I want to do is, if `diff(SalesItem)=1`, I want to combine the level of `SalesItem` into 1, for example: diff between `SalesItem` 1008 and 1009 equal to one, so, I want to rename `SalesItem` 1009 to 1008. So, later I can compute the sum of `Sales` for this `SalesItem` as one, because of my actual data=10,000, so, it is quite hard for me to do this one by one.

Is there any simplest way for me to do that?

Comment: Can you treat sales item as a numeric?  You seem to be using it as a factor, which goofs everything up, easiest to merge before making the data frame

Comment: What is the `diff` of '1008' and '1009'? Furthermore, even if we were to convert to numeric would be the correct answer for 1:10? All to become 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the fact that you have converted the first column to a factor indicates that you might need those factors in some place. so i would suggest that instead of changing any of the columns, add a third column to your data frame which will help you maintain the SalesItem relevant to that value. here are the steps for it :

```
> s1<-c('1008','1009','1012','1013','1016','1017','1018','1019','1054','1055')
> s2<-c(155,153,154,150,176,165,159,143,179,150)

> s1 = as.integer(s1)
> s3 = ifelse((s1-1) %in% s1, s1-1, s1)

> S <- data.frame(SalesItem=s1, Sales=s2, ItemId=s3)
```

then you can just count on the basis of the ItemId column.

Comment: Thanks All,,really appreciate your suggestions. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a terribly efficient solution, but since your data only contains 10000 records, it is not going to be a big problem.

Set up provided example data, but convert the SalesItem field to an integer so that the diff() operation makes sense.

```
> s1<-c('1008','1009','1012','1013','1016','1017','1018','1019','1054','1055')
> s2<-c(155,153,154,150,176,165,159,143,179,150)

> s1 = as.integer(s1)

> S<-data.frame(SalesItem=s1, Sales=s2)
```

Reorder data frame so that the SalesItem field is in ascending order (not necessary for current data set, but required for solution) then find the differences.

```
> S = S[order(S$SalesItem),]
> d = c(0, diff(S$SalesItem))
```

Duplicate the SalesItem data and then filter based on the values of the differences.

```
> labels = s1
> #
> for (n in 1:nrow(S)) {if (d[n] == 1) labels[n] = labels[n-1]}
> S$labels = labels
```

The (temporary) labels field now has the required new values for the SalesItem field. Once you are happy that this is doing the right thing, you can modify last line in above code to simply over-write the existing SalesItem field.

```
> S
   SalesItem Sales labels
1       1008   155   1008
2       1009   153   1008
3       1012   154   1012
4       1013   150   1012
5       1016   176   1016
6       1017   165   1016
7       1018   159   1016
8       1019   143   1016
9       1054   179   1054
10      1055   150   1054
```